# How to skip the windows authentication in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, web-config, impersonation

I have a solution in MVC5. That is using windows authentication, the web config has the following settings:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>
<allow users="?" />
</authorization>
```

I want to skip this windows authentication. That is setting a default username and password. For example

```
<username="Test" password="Password">
```

So that solution uses this user instead of windows user.

I want this because of some reason I have to develop the solution as a different windows user, that is not in an admin group. So some pages cannot be viewed by this user.

I have removed the authentication tag from web.config, But it's still not logging in when I enter the admin username and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just disable authentication:

```
<windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
```

Possible to impersonate:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <identity impersonate="true" userName="<domain>\<UserName>" password="<password>"/>
    ...
</system.web>
```

Comment: Thanks,  Is there any way to configure user name and password in web config? Like      

    <username="Test" password="Password">

Comment: Possibility to impersonate added

Comment: Jelle, it would help more if you include where those go in the Web.config file. Some people may not understand what section those lines go under